# Txt file into a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have looked at other posts here but I cant seem to find any help with what im specifically trying to do.

So I have data in 'food.txt'. It represents the annual consumption per capita and i have to open and read the txt file into a list of lists named data[]

```
FOOD |    1980    1985    1990    1995    2000    2005
-----+-------------------------------------------------
BEEF |    72.1    68.1    63.9    63.5    64.5    62.4
PORK |    52.1    49.2    46.4    48.4    47.8    46.5
FOWL |    40.8    48.5    56.2    62.1    67.9    73.6
FISH |    12.4    13.7    14.9    14.8    15.2    16.1
```

This is what i have so far, to make it into lines

```
data = []
filename = 'food.txt'
with open('food.txt' , 'r') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        data.append(line.strip().split(','))
```

This separates them in separate lines but I cant use this as inputs for graphs which is the second part that i know how to do. I should be able to call on it like i put below because this will only give the numerical values which is what i need.

```
years = data[0][1:]

porkconsumption = [2][1:]
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is this written in any particular language?

Comment: Can you show what at least some of your text file would be expected to correspond to in `data`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the language. I corrected it, its in python. The text file is the imgur link i posted. So porkconsumption[2][1:] would give me that entire row excluding the string 'pork'

Comment: Your link isn't to a text file.

Comment: I changed your data into text format, but we really really need you to paste your ACTUAL TEXT FILE in here. Not a picture thereof.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you have, after a processing, is a list with strings in it like so

```
['ABC 345 678','DEF 789 657']
```

Change your code to say `line.strip().split()`, and you will see your `data` list will be filled with lists like so:

```
[['ABC', '345', '678'],['DEF','789','657']]
```

Then loop through these to turn them into numbers you can plot:

```
pork = map(int,data[2][1:])
```